# Asp grid returning different data from what's on screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp gridview control that is bound to an xml datasource. The grid has paging enabled and I have a check box column for selecting rows.
I have implemented filtering/searching which seems to work - the data that comes back has only the searched for data in the specified column.  However when I click on a button the data that is in the code behind is not what I click on from the page.

Here is my gridview

```
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#cccccc" ForeColor="Black" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="ToggleCheckBoxes();" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox" runat="server"  OnClick="chkboxHandler(this);" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dob" HeaderText="DOB" />              
            <asp:BoundField DataField="col3" HeaderText="Col3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="col4" HeaderText="Col4" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="col5" HeaderText="Col5" />
       </asp:GridView>
```

The filtering markup is a drop down list to select  columns you can search on, a text field for the data being searched for and an asp:button to do execute the request.  Here is the code that gets called in the code behind when that button is clicked
      private void FilterGrid( string filterCol, string filterVal)
        {
            string filterRequestXml = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Filter.xml");

```
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.Load(filterRequestXml);
       //set filter by column
      XmlNode node1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("filter.column");
     node1.InnerText = filterCol;

       //set filter by value
      XmlNode node2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("filter.value");
     node2.InnerText = filterVal;

       string filteredReferralList =  GetHTTPResponse(doc.OuterXml, Session["webservice"].toString());
       DataTable dt = .ConvertXmlToDataTable(filteredReferralList);

        //Session["referrallist"] = dt;          
        this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;

        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

When the page reloads the data looks fine.

There is another button on the page named  'Click Me'
when I select a row - using the checkbox, then click that button in the code behind, the value of the id column is not what i chose. This is the problem I'm having.

Can someone help pls?

Thanks

Comment: First, I see OnClick="chkboxHandler(this);". Isn't that OnClientClick? For the "Click Me" button, I understand that it is outside of the GridView. When you click on it, how do you make the connection between the checked boxes and the id value? Do you use DataKeyNames?

Comment: I dont think there is an OnClientClick() for checkboxes so I had to use Onclick.  In the markup this puts a click event on the span that the checkbox is in.    I use this event to display an asp:button.  It is in the code behind of this button that I check the value of ID column.

Comment: My bad for the OnClientClick... For the code of the "Click Me" button, how do you get the corresponding value of the ID column? Since this is the part that does not work for you, it would be good to see the code.

Comment: protected void ClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows){
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkbox");
                    if (cb != null && cb.Checked) {
                       string PersonID = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;                                              
                        ProcessID(PersonID)
                    }
                }
                BindList(id)
        }

Comment: And what id value do you get? Is it the value of another row? The preferred way to get a value associated with a GridView row is to use DataKeyNames (in markup), instead of parsing the cell content. You can set DataKeyNames="id" (you can add more values if you want, separated with commas), then you can retrieve the value in code behind with GridView1.DataKey(row.RowIndex).Values("id").

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ConnorsFan. Using DataKeys was part of the solution. The other part was changing the way I implemented the filtering. For each page I hide the rows that dont satisfy the filter expression. So the user has to click filter on each page.